# Join two table show all record on left table if right table exists, use right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have table A:

```
ColA |  ColB          
  A  |   0    
  B  |   0      
  C  |   0
```

and table B:

```
ColA |  ColB          
  A  |   10    
  D  |   50
```

I want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN that if rows of right table exists then it will use right table else use the left table. The result I want is:

```
ColA |  ColB          
  A  |   10    
  B  |   0      
  C  |   0
```

Comment: What problem you faced in ur attempt?

Comment: I'm working with a report to count the total for "this week". First I will get current days of current week then get all the record of all date. After that I will to join current week date to all date to get the total of current week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    a.ColA,
    ISNULL(b.ColB, 0) AS B_ColB
FROM    dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
    a.ColA,
    ISNULL(b.ColB, a.ColB) AS B_ColB
FROM    dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d0af/1)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use Full outer join here...

here is an example

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
```